# Split file based on first matchof pattern

Tags: linux, shell

How can I split a text file based on the first match of a pattern? The file only needs to be split in 2 parts, one containing everything prior to the line matching the pattern, one containing the line matching, and everything after. The lines after it will also contain the pattern again, but that shouldn't trigger multiple parts.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed '/pattern/q' file.txt | grep -v "pattern" > part1.txt
sed -n `sed -n '/pattern/=' file.txt | head -1`',$p' file.txt > part2.txt
```

Where `file.txt` - your file

Comment: This is the best answer and saved me a bunch of time - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood the last sentence however:

This should copy all the line of your file till the line of the pattern excluded

```
head -n `grep -e "YOUR PATTERN" -n YOURFILE | head -1 | awk -F ":" '{print $1-1}'` YOURFILE > FIRST_FILE_OUTPUT.txt
```

this sould copy from the line of pattern included to the end.

```
tail -n `grep -e "YOUR PATTERN" -n YOURFILE | head -1 | awk -F ":" '{print "+"$1}'` YOURFILE > SECOND_FILE_OUTPUT.txt
```

where YOURFILE us the input file to split
YOUR PATTERN is the "key" you want to search in your file. 
FIRST_FILE_OUTPUT.txt and SECOND_FILE_OUTPUT.txt are the output file in which you'll find
the first and the second part of your file.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
awk -F'+' '{ print $1 }' < abc > firstpart.txt
awk -F'+' '{ print $1 }' < abc > secondpart.txt
```

Comment: That's the exact same command twice? This doesn't do anything.